# Replacing NULL value in current row based on 'closest' matching 'earlier' row. (date based table)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

I have the following mysql table

```
+---------------------+------+
| time                | val  |
+---------------------+------+
| 2005-02-03 00:00:00 | 2.11 |
| 2005-02-04 00:00:00 | 2.11 |
| 2005-02-05 00:00:00 | NULL |
| 2005-02-06 00:00:00 | NULL |
| 2005-02-07 00:00:00 | 3.43 |
| 2005-02-08 00:00:00 | NULL |
| 2005-02-09 00:00:00 | NULL |
| 2005-02-10 00:00:00 | 5.66 |
| 2005-02-11 00:00:00 | 5.66 |
| 2005-02-12 00:00:00 | NULL |
+---------------------+------+
```

I want to create an algorithm (in PHP) that fill the NULL values based on the last non-null value. So the table will become the following

```
+---------------------+------+
| time                | val  |
+---------------------+------+
| 2005-02-03 00:00:00 | 2.11 |
| 2005-02-04 00:00:00 | 2.11 |
| 2005-02-05 00:00:00 |>2.11 |
| 2005-02-06 00:00:00 |>2.11 |
| 2005-02-07 00:00:00 | 3.43 |
| 2005-02-08 00:00:00 |>3.43 |
| 2005-02-09 00:00:00 |>3.43 |
| 2005-02-10 00:00:00 | 5.66 |
| 2005-02-11 00:00:00 | 5.66 |
| 2005-02-12 00:00:00 |>5.66 |
+---------------------+------+
```

I'm looking for clues on how to approach this situation. I'm using PHP-Laravel.

There is an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91918/1) here for 'standard' SQL.

Comment: Drew is right that should be a SQL on insert function. But when the only tool you have is an hammer then every problem becomes a nail.

Comment: apparently he didn't like my comment and had it flagged. Shoot the messenger, no problem

Comment: @Drew nope I didn't, which left me confused about Jamin comment. Can you please repost it.

Comment: I guess there are high ranking PHP enthusiasts out there so I will refrain. I use PHP a ton, I just don't use it for this purpose. Once you get your Answer, I will show you another way, maybe by pigeon message delivery

Comment: But @JaminQuimby, a lot of this stuff is after the fact patching of data

Comment: Thanks @Drew. If you have a MySql solution it'll be even better since from my experience it's faster on larger scale DBs. Can you please post it as an answer?

Comment: I will at some point, or someone will, I was focusing on this that you wrote: I want to create an algorithm (**in PHP**)

Comment: @Drew Changed it to "solution". I have to be honest that I lack mysql experience so I'm not aware of its full capabilities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As comments indicate, you should be fixing this when you populate the table. That said, it can be done in PHP or MySQL. Here is one option:

```
SET @x:=0;
SELECT `time`, IF(val IS NOT NULL, @x:=val, @x) AS val
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY `time`;
```

Bear in mind that your result will change depending on ordering and `WHERE` and so on. Use `SET @x:=0;` to define your default value for cases when first row has `NULL` value.

If you need to fix the data permanently, rather than for single query, you can update the table with 'correct' values:

```
SET @x:=0;
UPDATE yourtable SET val=IF(val IS NOT NULL, @x:=val, @x) 
 ORDER BY `time`;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use just SQL, you could use this UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE
  tab INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      t1.time,
      MAX(t2.time) prev_time
    FROM
      tab t1 INNER JOIN tab t2
      ON t1.time>t2.time
    WHERE
      t1.val IS NULL
      AND t2.val IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
      t1.time
  ) p ON tab.time = p.time
  INNER JOIN tab t2 ON p.prev_time = t2.time
SET
  tab.val = t2.val
```

Please see a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2695c/1).

The subquery will return, for every NULL row the previous date with a non-NULL value. Then I'm joining the table with itself to get the value and to update the null row.